# Reading Keycode / Keychar from software keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, char, keycode

what I need is:

1. Bring up the software keyboard on a button click. There are lots of answers here for that.
2. As soon as the user presses any key on the softwarekeyboard (except switch ime, ... ) I want to trigger a listener which transmits the keycode / keychar to another method. So if the user presses `a` I want to either receive `'a'` or `65` (keycode for `a`).

Is there something like that already available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an onKeyDown listener which, by default, passes the key code into the event handler.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Lod.d("ON KEY DOWN", "KEY CODE: " + keyCode);

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Remember to return a value here since the event handler requires a return type of **boolean**.